# C# LINQ Query DateTime literal generated

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, firebird

We are using the following code to generate SQL code to query against a firebird database;

```
DSRCash.GetAll(x => x.Account.ID == Account.ID
                 && x.Date_Record <= dateTO
                 && x.Date_Record >= dateFROM).ToList();
```

Both dateTO and dateFROM parameters are non nullable DateTime and this is the same for their respective database columns.

The SQL where clause generated is as follows;

```
where  (struct_cas0_.DELETED IS NULL)
       and struct_cas0_.ACCOUNT_ID = 372 /* @p0 */
       and struct_cas0_.DATE_RECORD <= '2011-02-18T13:00:00.00' /* @p1 */
       and struct_cas0_.DATE_RECORD >= '2010-02-17T13:00:00.00' /* @p2 */
```

You can see the DateTime literal has been formatted using "s" or Standard Sortable format. It appears that Firebird does not support this date format, if we remove the "T" from the datetime literal the query will execute successfully.

Is it possible to change the DateTime conversion to string that is being performed?

I should also mention that we are using NHibernate as an ORM for this project.

Comment: Is that Ayende's profiler? It is trying to tell you that this is actually a parameter - @p1 / @p2 - so it really comes down to: how are @p1 / @p2 declared? as [n][var]char? or as datetime?

Comment: Why ask twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037711/nhibernate-datetime-for-query-overflow-exception-caused-by-string-format

Comment: Yes, the SQL output is from the profiler. Are you implying that the issue may be related to NHibernate creating the parameters?

Comment: Daniel ... because after investigation I am assuming the problem is not related to the database but the SQL generated by the expression. Have I committed a crime?

Comment: In my opinion it is the same question and the answers are very similar. You will have two separate discussions about the same problem. The better way would have been to edit your original question.

Comment: i agree ... can we close this (delete it) or point it to the previous question. I am a SO newbie!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use an expression visitor that when encountering a date takes two paths.
1. If it is a constant - replace it with a string formatted correctly with a convert to datetime
2. If it is a MemberExpression do nothing.

This will change your sql to

where  (struct_cas0_.DELETED IS NULL)
       and struct_cas0_.ACCOUNT_ID = 372 /* @p0 */
       and struct_cas0_.DATE_RECORD <= CAST('2011-02-18' AS DATETIME) /* @p1 */
       and struct_cas0_.DATE_RECORD >= CAST('2010-02-18' AS DATETIME) /* @p2 */